# how an index value can be used to retrieve the respective name(string)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

By using the listdlg its possible to select the file from list, but it returns the respective index as a output but not the name(string of selected entity)of the selection. how can one get the name of the selected file in output??'

for example

```
[Selection, ok] = listdlg(Name,Value,...);

% selection is nothing but a index of selected entities.
```

Comment: I have updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog box is filled with a cell array provided as the value of the `ListString` parameter. The result of the call to `listdlg` is the index into this cellarray.

Consider the following code:

```
filelist=dir("/home");
S={filelist.name};
[Selection,ok]=listdlg('ListString',S,'SelectionMode','single');
if (ok) filename=cell2mat(S(Selection)) endif
```

If the selection of the item `user1` was made it should output

```
filename = user1
```

**Update**

When `SelectionMode` is `multiple`, you could use `celldisp(S(Selection))`. To extract individual items use `S{Selection(i)}` where `i` ranges from 1 to `length(Selection)`.

```
filelist=dir("/home");
S={filelist.name};
[Selection,ok]=listdlg('ListString',S,'SelectionMode','multiple');
if (ok) 
  for i=1:length(Selection)
    disp(S{Selection(i)}) 
  end
endif
```